# Parse floats from a string

Tags: java, performance, parsing, floating-point, svg

While fixing some old code I came up with a class that parses floats from a string.

This is used for parsing svg files in xml format. Floats can be separated by comma, space or anything at all in case the next number starts with a sign. They can also use exponential notation.

Sample:

```
<path d="
    M245.792,247.275c0.828,1.036,0.794,2.333,0.924,3.53c0.161,1.442,0.122,2.924,0.016,4.377c-0.109,1.469-0.365,2.93-0.626,4.382
    c-0.353,1.946-0.965,3.814-1.914,5.563c-0.365,0.67-0.647,1.397-1.086,2.019c-0.804,1.14-1.705,2.212-2.548,3.326
    c-1.484,1.967-3.566,3.112-5.648,4.304c-1.356,0.778-2.707,1.553-4.194,1.98c-2.577,0.742-5.196,1.243-7.904,0.672
    c-1.02-0.213-2.065-0.286-3.099-0.44c-2.901-0.436-4.463-2.366-5.446-4.917c-0.84-2.179-0.598-4.317,0.067-6.526
    c0.899-2.974,2.905-5.095,4.931-7.278c1.564-1.688,3.005-3.498,4.384-5.339c1.188-1.581,0.951-2.972-0.513-4.263
    c-1.453-0.238-1.456-0.238-2.139,1.176c-1.119,2.31-2.463,4.513-4.409,6.169c-2.983,2.536-6.378,4.271-10.45,4.197
    c-3.49-0.062-6.985-0.234-10.473-0.174c-1.821,0.03-3.679,0.295-5.442,0.754c-1.948,0.508-3.091,2.061-3.743,3.915
    c-0.615,1.764-0.973,3.642-1.755,5.324c-1.615,3.472-3.705,6.573-7.654,7.836c-0.857,0.273-1.614,0.861-2.471,1.143
    c-2.482,0.814-5.011,0.832-7.585,0.362c-1.683-0.308-3.407-0.384-4.915-1.309c-1.85-1.138-3.589-2.405-4.922-4.163
    c-0.35-0.46-0.777-0.859-1.171-1.287"/>
```

This is the class:

```
private class ParserData
{
    String s;
    int cur = 0;
    int len = 0;

    float prev_x = .0f;
    float prev_y = .0f;

    float prev_cx = .0f;
    float prev_cy = .0f;

    float start_x = .0f;
    float start_y = .0f;

    char prev_curve;
    char next_curve = 0;

    public void setData(String data)
    {
        s = data;
        len = s.length();

        cur = 0;
        prev_x = 0;
        prev_y = 0;

        prev_cx = .0f;
        prev_cy = .0f;

        start_x = .0f;
        start_y = .0f;

        prev_curve = 0;
        next_curve = 0;         
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return cur < len;
    }

    public char getNext()
    {
        return s.charAt(cur++);
    }

    public char peekNext()
    {
        return s.charAt(cur);
    }

    public void skipSpaces()
    {
        while(hasNext())
        {
            char c = s.charAt(cur);

            switch(c)
            {
            case ' ':
            case ',':
            case '\n':
            case '\t':
            case '\r':
                break;

            default:
                return;
            }

            cur++;
        }
    }

    private float parseFloat()
    {
        boolean exp = false;
        boolean last = false;

        skipSpaces();

        int j = cur;

        if(s.charAt(j) == '-')
        {
            getNext();
        }

        while(hasNext() && !last)
        {
            char c = getNext();

            switch(c)
            {
                case '0':
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                case '6':
                case '7':
                case '8':
                case '9':
                case '+':
                case '.':
                    exp = false;
                    break;

                case '-':
                    if(exp)
                    {
                        exp = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cur--;
                        return Uti.safeParseFloat(s.substring(j, cur));
                    }
                    break;

                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                    exp = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    cur--;
                    return Uti.safeParseFloat(s.substring(j, cur));
            }
        }

        return Uti.safeParseFloat(s.substring(j, cur));
    }
}
```

While `hasNext` is true `getNext` is used to read the type of element, then `parseFloat` is called to get all the points and so on. For example, "c" is a cubic bezier curve and after it there are 3 control points (3 comma separated pairs, or 6 floats) to read.

I'm looking for some ways to speed up the process.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/3sJsgLqy) is the full code of the content handler.

Comment: Can you add a code example for how you use this class?

Comment: It is used in the handler of a sax parser, here is the code: http://pastebin.com/r7VM7NSp

Answer (score 5):

At least for now, I did not look at improving performance or at the general approach, but at some more basic things I think would improve the readability of the code.

**`setData` vs Constructor**

It seems to me that `setData` takes the role of a constructor here. In that case, I would just make it a constructor instead of making it a method. Sure, this would result in the creation of a new object, but it would result in cleaner code (the `ParserData` would always be a valid object).

**Naming**

First of all, in Java CamelCase is used instead of underscores. It's always good to follow the conventions of a language, so `prev_curve` for example should be `prevCurve`.

Variables should always have expressive names, but this is especially important at class level. Your names wouldn't tell me the difference between `prev_x` and `prev_cx` for example. `s` is also not a very expressive name (I cannot think of a name that's a lot better, but even `string` or `inputString` would be better. For consistency, `data` should then be changed to the same name).

`len` could be `length`, `cur` `currentPosition`, and `c` could be `currentChar`.

`exp` should probably be `exponent` and `j` also should get a more expressive name (something like `startFloatString`).

**access modifiers**

Your fields should be `private`.

Your `skipSpaces` should probably be `private` as well.

The `parseFloat` method is private, and not called from within the class. But it is the main parse method. This seems wrong, I would make it public.

**Unused Fields**

Defining fields and then not using them is not good practice. You should remove `next_curve`, `prev_curve`, `start_y`, `start_x`, `prev_cy`, `prev_cx`, `prev_y` and `prev_x`. I see that you do use these fields in a different context, but not in your parsing code. So I would create a new class for them instead of tagging them onto this one.

You should also remove `last` and change

> while(hasNext() && !last)

to

```
while(hasNext())
```

**Use methods that you have defined**

You have `getNext`, so why not use it in `skipSpaces` instead of getting the character yourself and then increasing `cur`.

Same with `peekNext` in `parseFloat`.

**Formating**

In Java, it is customary to put the `{` on the same line, not the next.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I updated my question with the updated code.

Comment: @キキジキ sure, glad to help :) But I have to role back your edit (please see [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)). You could wait for some more answers, and then post a follow-up question.

Comment: Oh sorry, got it.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing character by character is going to be slow.
Perhaps you could consider alternative implementations:

- Split the string with a regular expressions
- Use a regular expression to match the numbers and iterate over the matches

Here's an example:

```
public static List<Float> parse(String data) {
    String[] parts = data.replaceAll("[^\\d.-]|(?=-)", " ").trim().split(" +");
    List<Float> numbers = new ArrayList<>(parts.length);
    for (String s : parts) {
        numbers.add(Float.parseFloat(s));
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

For the sample you gave, this method will return a list with numbers:

> ```
>  245.792, 247.275, -0.828, 1.036, 0.794, 2.333, 0.924, 3.53, 0.161, 1.442, ...
> ```

For other approaches using regular expressions,
see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225235/extracting-numbers-from-a-string-in-java-by-splitting-on-a-regex) on stackoverflow (I asked just for this question ;-)

Comment: I also need to get the letters that define curves inside the path, like "c" "C" "s" "S" ... For example, when a "c" comes I read the next 6 floats and generate a cubic spline, "v" I read one value and add a vertical line and so on.

Comment: It's probably not a good test but, I tried ignoring the problem above and feeding a file with only numbers to both versions. With regexp I get 2.5x worse performance. Source and data file -> http://pastebin.com/nV9eaaFW http://pastebin.com/ZUtgdvEY